# Django template reload div with javascript - url tag

Tags: ajax, django, django-templates, django-urls

Hi i just wanted to reload part of data on the website using ajax.

Website is created using template language from Django.

I have problem with using url tag inside javascript tags, code below.

**urls.py**

```
 urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^(?P<place_id>[\w]+)/$', place_views.place_website, 
  name='room_view'),
  ]
```

**Website**

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            setInterval(function () {

                $("#displayMoment").load("{% url room_view room_id %}");

            }, 60000);
            </script>
```

**Legend**

room_view is the name of the view inside views.py

room_id is the room id which is captured by regex in url pattern. But it should be in double bracket right ? {{ room_id }}  ?

displayMoment is the id of the DIV.

**Problem**

With this i get error

```
NoReverseMatch at /places/2/
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Ho does the website part should look like ?

Comment: You have a typo `{% url room_view room_id %}` this should be `{% url 'room_view' room_id %}`

Comment: @ArpitSolanki  thanks a lot !!!! its working ;]  this is so embarrassing ;)